# Algolia InstantSearchjs Vue dynamic widgets

Tags: vue.js, algolia, instantsearch.js, vue-instant-search

We have an implementation of Algolia search using the InstantSearch Vue components.

My understanding is that Algolia can dynamically show facets depending on the items in the search result - for example, showing 'memory' if there are a large proportion of mobile phones in the results, 'size' if there are a large proportion of TVs, etc.

We're trying to accomplish this using the `ais-dynamic-widgets` component. We've set up the facets and the facet display in the dashboard.

From the name, you'd expect `ais-dynamic-widgets` to dynamically show widgets - but from our experience and the examples in the docs it appears it's still required to manually list the facet widgets within the component:

```
<ais-dynamic-widgets>
  <ais-refinement-list attribute="brand" />
  <ais-panel>
    <ais-menu attribute="categories" />
  </ais-panel>
  <ais-hierarchical-menu :attributes="['categories']" />
</ais-dynamic-widgets>
```

Using Vue Inspector I can see that `ais-dynamic-widgets` is aware of the defined facets - they appear in `data.state.attributesToRender`:

[image: Vue Inspector showing defined facets]

I would expect to be able to do something like:

```
<ais-dynamic-widgets>
  <ais-refinement-list v-for="attr in data.state.attributesToRender" :key="attr" :attribute="attr" />
</ais-dynamic-widgets>
```

But:

1. I can't find a way to reference this data (likely my lack of Vue skills
2. If this did work, will it automatically only show applicable facets?